# MVC C# "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem with my solution. I am trying to create an MVC application wherein the view has a textbox for a string, a dropdown list for sorting type(e.g bubble sort,quick sort) and a button to sort the string.

here is my code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult total(string value1, String calci)
    {
        char[] total;
        switch (calci)
        {
            case "bubbleSort":
                total = value1.ToCharArray();
                char temp;
                for (int write = 0; write < total.Length; write++)
                    for (int sor = 0; sor < total.Length - 1; sor++)
                        if (total[sor] > total[sor + 1])
                        {
                            temp = total[sor + 1];
                            total[sor + 1] = total[sor];
                            total[sor] = temp;
                        }
                return Content("Result " + total);

        }
    }
```

it keeps giving me an error of "not all code paths return a value"
I really need to run this program, also ignore the "total" from my actionresult because my the original solution of this project is my calculator project.Thankyou!

Comment: could be wrong but I think you need a `break;` at the end of your case. Also a `default` case should be included.

Comment: @CapnJack: No; that isn't reachable because of the `return`.

Comment: Add the default case inside the switch, or a return at the end of your method.

Comment: @SLaks true, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you only have a return value in your `switch` statement. If the case is `"bubbleSort"` the there isn't anything to return! Whenever you have a method with a return type other than void, you need to ensure all possible routes have a return value of the type specified when creating your class.

You can resolve this by adding a default case statement that returns a result as well. Try adding this after your first `case`:

```
default:
    return Content(@"Unhandled 'calci' parameter: " + calci);
```

Comment: See `default:` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Answer (score 2):

You will need a default case such as this:

```
        switch (calci)
        {
            case "bubbleSort":
                total = value1.ToCharArray();
                char temp;
                for (int write = 0; write < total.Length; write++)
                for (int sor = 0; sor < total.Length - 1; sor++)
                    if (total[sor] > total[sor + 1])
                    {
                        temp = total[sor + 1];
                        total[sor + 1] = total[sor];
                        total[sor] = temp;
                    }
                return Content("Result " + total);
            default:
                return Content("Result 0");                    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need to make sure that your function *always* returns a value.

Even if `calci` is not `"bubbleSort"`.